# What is the capacitor in this typical application for?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I've been looking at the TC1252 voltage regulator [(datasheet available here)](https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/21373b-68613.pdf), but can't figure out what the purpose of the second capacitor (connected between VOUT and GND) in the typical application circuit example (page 3).

EDIT: Schematic Below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP94sa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: please use the included schematic editor to draw the circuit diagram ... then click "save & include" to add the diagram into your post

Comment: Section 3.1 explains why it is needed. Its primary function is to keep the regulator from oscillating. It also acts as a bulk capacitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the output capacitor. Per the datasheet a minimum output capacitance of 1uF is required for stability.  Most linear regulators require external output capacitance for their control loop to be stable. Note that the minimum is just that, and it is usually better to use the recommended value if you can. Most datasheets will indicate a recommended range.